# QML: How to create a 3 state custom button made from images?

Tags: qt, qml

So I try:

```
   Rectangle {
       x: 617
       y: 450
   Image {
      id: rect
      source:  "buttons/GO/GO!-norm.png"
      smooth: true
      opacity: 1
      MouseArea {
          id: mouseArea
          anchors.fill: parent
          hoverEnabled: true         //this line will enable mouseArea.containsMouse
          onClicked: Qt.quit()
      }

      states:  [
           State {
               name: "mouse-over"; when: mouseArea.containsMouse
               PropertyChanges { target: rect; scale: 0.95; opacity: 0; }
               PropertyChanges { target: rect2; scale: 0.95; opacity: 1}
               PropertyChanges { target: rect3; scale: 0.95; opacity: 0}
           },

            State {
               name: "mouse-down"; when: mouseArea.pressedButtons
               PropertyChanges { target: rect; scale: 0.95; opacity: 0; }
               PropertyChanges { target: rect2; scale: 0.95; opacity: 0}
               PropertyChanges { target: rect3; scale: 0.95; opacity: 1}
           }
       ]

       transitions: Transition {
           NumberAnimation { properties: "scale, opacity"; easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad; duration: 500  }
       }
   }

   Image {
      id: rect2
      source:  "buttons/GO/GO!-over.png"
      smooth: true
      opacity: 0
      anchors.fill: rect

     }

   Image {
      id: rect3
      source:  "buttons/GO/GO!-down.png"
      smooth: true
      opacity: 0
      anchors.fill: rect

     }
   }
```

but it works only in over\out states... How to make my button have 3 states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what happens but it's possible: When you mouseover the image, its opacity gets set to 0. The [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-item.html#opacity-prop) says that:

1. Changing opacity affects also the child items of the Item.
2. If an item's opacity is set to 0, the item will no longer receive mouse events.

Thus, when you mouseover, the `rect.opacity` is set to 0, `mouseArea` stops receiving mouse events and the `mouseArea.pressedButtons` condition is never fulfilled. You can probably avoid this by making `mouseArea` a sibling of the `Image` and not its child item. Use an `Item` or `Rectangle` as the parent item.

Comment: Yes, opacity: 0 is like visible: false. The item stops to exist.
Another way could be to set opacity to 0.01 instead of 0, but I consider your solution to be cleaner because it separates the mouse area from the view (the image).

Comment: Yes, I also considered as a second solution to set the opacity to a very low non-zero value. That requires a smaller change to existing code and works fine at least if the images are somewhat similar.